# errors that occurred when activating anaconda environment

Tags: python, anaconda, miniconda

I'm trying to solve an error that occurred during environment application.

Error log:

```
C:\Users\user\Miniconda2\Scripts>conda env create -n klustaview -f 
C:\Users\user\Downloads\environment-win.yml
Fetching package metadata ...........
Solving package specifications: .

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - numpy 1.8.2 py27_0
  - pandas 0.12.0 np17py27_1 -> numpy 1.7*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

I guess it's because of the pip I installed prior.

How could I solve this conflict problem?

Comment: Please check this [documentation](https://docs.continuum.io/docs_oss/conda/py2or3#create-a-python-3-5-environment) for creating a conda environment with support for python 2.x and 3.x versions

Comment: I think you are creating conda environment using yml file. Please read this [post](https://thinkingvirtually.blogspot.in/2017/08/anaconda-environment-setup-import-tensorflow-solved.html), it explains more about conda prompt using anaconda navigator.